# Python and Android

Tags: android, python

[This](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)  link says that it is indeed possible to write code in **Python** and use it for app development in **android** platform. I would like to know what the catch is when using Python and not Java. Is there any compromise being made in speed of execution or size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link you posted:

> Scripts can be run interactively in a terminal, in the background, or via Locale.

This already is a disadvantage, as you can't release your Apps to Android Market easily. This can however ostensibly be avoided by the build script of [Pygame Subset for Android,](http://pygame.renpy.org/) but I am not sure about this. The Python interpreter will however need to be installed on the device, which will bloat the App's size by quite a bit.

The speed of execution of Python on an Android device of course is slower than Java, as Python doesn't magically accelerate just because it runs on a phone. The difference isn't that great in most situations, though.

Comment: i did saw from a related question that the script can be converted into .apk , then will there be problems on releasing to Android Market?.

Have you tried using S4LA?

Comment: I haven't, but it seems that this is actually possible. >ou may want to check this link, which explains how to release a script to the Android Market: http://jokar-johnk.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-make-android-app-with-sl4a.html